Flutter build web, add an extra folder for my assets
My project tree is made this way

/root/assets/categorias.json

but when I run "flutter build web" my project tree changes to this

/root/assets/assets/categorias.json

how can I avoid this?
This is my pubspec.yml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/categorias.json

In debug mode works perfect, but when I upload the website to github (for free hosting) stops working. Thank you very much guys from Honduras.
I tried asking chatGPT, move the files after compiling to match the structure. I am expecting a solution.

how do you access the categorias.json in your code?

Change
assets:
    - assets/categorias.json

To
assets:
    - /categorias.json

and you should be good.
